# Why didn't Elizabeth get cursed?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, curse-of-the-black-pearl

In Pirates of the Caribbean, whoever has the Aztec gold gets cursed.

But Elizabeth had the gold coin with her which Bootstrap gave to his son Will before he was tied to a cannon and dropped to the ocean floor.

Barbossa states that they were cursed because of Aztec gold.

Also in the fight between Jack and Barbossa, Jack takes a gold coin and he was also cursed.

Why didn't Elizabeth get affected? Or was she also cursed and nobody noticed?

Comment: I think you have to physically remove the treasure yourself to be cursed. It doesn't get passed on.

Comment: My reading is that 'if any mortal removes *but* a single piece...'. Jack Sparrow certainly palmed one, and received the curse. So, it seems to imply that Jack already had taken one at some time...?

Comment: He takes during the conversation with Barbossa, like few mins before it is revealed that he becomes immortal.

Comment: It's weird that you focus on Elizabeth and not Will, who she got it from.

Answer (score 38):

Elizabeth didn't get cursed because **she didn't take the coin from its original chest**, the coin got passed on to Will Turner and then Elizabeth, Bill Turner was the one that took that same coin from the chest and he got cursed.

Quote from conversation between Barbossa and Elizabeth about the curse:

> "...So the heathen gods placed upon the gold...a terrible curse. Any
>   mortal that removes but a single piece **from that stone chest** shall
>   be punished for eternity."

The crew that stole the gold from the original chest got cursed, but before they realized that, they already spent their aztec gold on different places.

If the curse was spread just by touching the gold there would be a lot more undead people, including Elizabeth and Will, which is not the case.

Confusion might be when Jack took the gold coin from the original stone chest later on and gotten cursed for a short period until he returned it back.

Comment: where did you get that quote, as it disagrees with the script as I read it.

Comment: From PoC wiki,that's the quote as I remember from the movie I watched.Here is the only clip I managed to find of that part online http://youtu.be/Lu_oqP4JB3g?t=3m20s

Comment: Jack touched the coin only just for short time but got cursed. Why didn't it affect Elizabeth? I am afraid you again failed to answer my question

Comment: @ArunkumarTK: This answer seems to pretty clearly say that Jack took the coin from the chest whereas Elizabeth didn't. How is that failing to answer your question? If you have objections to the answer you should probably make them clearer.

Comment: That quote is from the movie, directly. It may have been changed from the script while the movie was being filmed, but it agrees completely with what actually happens.

Comment: @Chris Are you saying that each of the pirate took their share of gold from the chest themselves? I dont think so. If I was the captain, I will not allow anyone near the chest and by myself give everyone their share.

Comment: @ArunkumarTK: I was not saying anything except that this answer addresses your question and that if you didn't think so you should make your objections clearer as you now have. As for your objections I will now state that from the youtube clip it does suggest that the curse effects those that take the treasure from the chest. This clearly explains the difference between Jack and Elizabeth. We have no evidence to suggest that the captain didn't let people take their share from the chest so it seems like the most likely answer. Anything else requires making things up which isn't necessary.

Comment: @Chris Sorry.. No offence.. I think CGCampbell's answer is moreover syncing with my ques

Comment: @ArunkumarTK: No worries. I'm not going to take offence. I just wanted to make my point clear. Though CGCampbell's answer does seem to be reliant on a movie script that may not be the one actually used in the final film (if the youtube video linked above is to be believed) which to my mind at least invalidates his answer. That is why the site has voting though. I agree with this answer and so upvoted it but I don't agree with the other so it didn't get an upvote. If you choose to accept the other then that's your choice. I will think you were wrong but I am sure you can live with that. :)

Comment: @CGCampbell - good luck setting stone chest on fire xD ... They could have tried to smash through it,but I wouldn't be surprised if the chest was indestructible...and still if they managed to destroy it they would get cursed anyway since breaking the chest would probably count as removing coins from it.

Comment: @ArunkumarTK - I don't think they ever mentioned that every single member of the crew got cursed,the story in the "Curse of the black pearl" is set about 10 years after the curse,those who didn't get cursed could have already died or simply left the ship when they realized it is full of undead people :O ...why would they spend 10 more years trying to break the curse they don't have.

Comment: Also there were 100 crew members at max and there were almost 900 coins,it's a handful of coins for each member...Barbossa overthrow Jack Sparrow by promising the crew that gold it really wouldn't work in his favor to take the coins for himself...There isn't too much hierarchy in the pirate world,most likely everyone that was there just dug their hands in the chest after Barbossa...Which could be the reason they didn't even move the chest from where they found it.

Comment: @Arun: Jack didn't just touch the coin for a short time. He picked up several coins and dropped them back into the chest, **but kept one**. We don't see the coin but the camera lingers on his hand as he palms it (like a magician hides a card in the palm of their hand). This is also the coin that he will later throw at Will to lift the curse again, thus killing Barbossa at the right time.

Answer (score 15):

For the same reason that young Will Turner wasn't cursed after *wearing* the medallion. After young Will is rescued in the beginning of the first movie, young Elizabeth finds the medallion on young Will, and not wanting him arrested and hung as a pirate, takes it and begins wearing it herself. Neither of them were cursed by that act.

It wasn't the simple act of holding, or *being given* a piece of eight from the cursed treasure. It was the personal *choice of stealing* one.

- Bootstrap Bill takes a coin (with greed, as treasure) and is cursed.
- Bootstrap gives the coin to his son (who receives it as a gift without envy or greed), who is not cursed.
- Elizabeth takes the coin with the good intention of saving Will (not with envy or greed), and is not cursed.
- Captain Jack Sparrow later takes a coin off the pile (with the bad intention of killing Barbossa) and is cursed.
- Finally Jack (the monkey) steals a doubloon (with greed, as treasure) and is cursed.

Just for @Logarr:

> ```
>                 BARBOSSA
>      Would that I could.
> ```
>
> He produces the medallion, lets it dangle from his fingers.
>
> ```
>                BARBOSSA (CONT'D)
>
>      Do you not know what this is,
>       then?
>
>                ELIZABETH
>      It's a pirate medallion.
>
>                BARBOSSA
>      It's a piece of the treasure of Isla de
>       Muerta .
> ```
>
> Elizabeth gives an infinitesimal shrug, intrigued despite
>   herself.
>
> ```
>                BARBOSSA (CONT 'D)
>      Ah, so you don't know as much as you
>       pretend. Back when Cortes was cutting a
>       great bloody swath through the New
>       World, a high priest gave. him all the
>       gold they had, with one condition: that
>       he spare the people's lives. Of course,
>       Cortes being Cortes, he didn't.
>          (nods)
>      He'd've made a great pirate, that one.
> ```
>
> Barbossa stands, moves to a shelf. Puts a key to a medium-
>   sized polished wooden box -- the Captain's chest. Opens it.
>
> ```
>                BARBOSSA (CONT'D)
>      So the priest, with his dying breath,
>       called on the power of the blood of his
>       people, and put on the gold a curse. If
>       anyone took so much as a single piece,
>       as he was compelled by greed, by greed
>       he would be consumed.
> ```
>
> Inside the chest are charts, some gold, a sextant -- and a
>   few pages of a Mayan CODEX, pieces of tree bark inscribed
>   with Mayan glyphs. Barbossa removes them carefully, sets
>   them on the table. Pours over them.
>
> ```
>                BARBOSSA (CONT'D)
>      Within a day of leaving port for Spain,
>       the treasure ship carrying the gold ...
>       something went wrong. The ship run
>       aground, every man aboard dead, save
>       one. He survived long enough to hide
>       the gold ashore.
>
>          (beat)
>      Over time, the dark magic of the curse
>       seeped into the place, making it a
>       cursed island. An island of death. Isla
>       de Muerta.
> ```
>
> *from [Pirates-of-the-Caribbean](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean.html)*

As you can read: *...put on the gold a curse. If anyone took so much as a single piece, as he was compelled by greed, by greed he would be consumed.*

The curse was not on the chest, but the gold. And for the curse to be "activated" the gold doubloon needed to be taken, with greed as the motive.

Comment: I doubt there's anything to do with intent in regards to the curse. It's a simple matter of "Did they take it out of the chest or not?"

Comment: "Jack Sparrow later takes a coin off the pile (with the bad intention of killing Barbossa)" - this is not my reading. He took the coin so he couldn't be killed. He was also wanting to kill barbossa but I don't see that the coin helped him to kill, just stopped him from being killed... Also your phrasing in your second paragraph needs adjusting. Its clearly not "the personal choice of stealing one" since Elizabeth she did steal it, no matter what her intentions were (I certainly don't remember her being given it or having permission to take it).

Comment: Just curious, are those quotes from an old script or from the actual finished movie?

Comment: @MacCooper: From the video linked from the comments in another answer it suggests that this is not the final script. The site it comes from doesn't seem to have a reference that I can see offhand to suggest whether this is an old version, user error or something else.

Answer (score 10):

My reading of the situation is that the curse only affects someone if they take it from the chest.

Comment: It's probably more a case of *intent.* The pirates with the stolen gold didn't all necessarily take it from the chest **physically,** but were party to the thievery.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Well it might be that the curse is mildly "intelligent" in that it can tell that the pirates were all thieving from the chest. They all took a share of the chest. If it were just a matter of "who physically removed it", then they'd just have the monkey pass it to each of them one by one.

Comment: They didn't know about the in advance did they?

Answer (score 1):

Barbossa explains it in the movie.  The person is cursed if they remove the gold from the stone chest.  Elizabeth nor Will did this ergo; not cursed.  Each person who was cursed physically removed gold from the chest on the Isla de Muerta.  It may not be in the script, but it's on film.